# Selecting data from specific times

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am having trouble getting a query that only displays results between 6am yesterday and 6am today.  Using sql server 2008.  I have a timestamp column with type datetime

Comment: Share your actual query please

Comment: i only have the select and from lines just need the where clause

Comment: Which precision you need (hours/minutes/seconds/milliseconds)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where ts_col between 
             dateadd(hour, 6, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -1))   
             and dateadd(hour, 6, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0));
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acd39/14)

Comment: sorry should of said it needs to be based on the current day so it will always work.  ie in a week I can just run it and it will pull back data for the previous day

Comment: thnx for sqlfiddle link. Didn't knew this site

Answer (score 0):

`where DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE), ts_column) BETWEEN -21600 AND 21600`